# Some fields like text box or dropdown fields dont appears when i navigate to specific url using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Not always 4/10 times some fields doesn't appears on web page when I navigate to given URL.

For example if there are 10 fields like first name, middle name, gender etc
when I navigate to URL using selenium script then some times middle name & gender fields wont appear on the webpage.

Please any one has a solution.

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you try? What site are you testing?

Comment: Did you tried wait for the elements?

Comment: i am testing an micro finance application on local host. To create a loan product i navigate to loan product url there  2 fields like interest type and interest recalculation fields wont appear on web page. @striter for each field i am using wait.until(ExpectedConditions
     .visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));